# How to redirect the page with history.push() function

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I have worked on a sign in page and this is a page for controlling
   unauthorized access. But, Page redirection is not working here,

```
Here is my code   

import React from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb, Button } from 'antd';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);     
  }  
state= {
      redirect: false,
  }

 render()
{
 let users=localStorage.getItem('user');
 function logOut() {
 if (true) {
 localStorage.clear();
 this.props.history.push('/Signin');
    }
    }
function AuthPage () {
return(
     <div>      
   { 
       (users) ? (<Layout>

   <Content>
              <div className="main-content">
                    <Link to="/Profile">Profile {users}</Link> | 
                    <Link to="/Topics">Topics</Link> | 
                   <Button onClick={logOut} type="link" >Logout</Button>
              </div> 
          </Content>
        </Layout> 
        ) : (<div>Need to login</div>
            )
   }
   </div>
 );
 }
   return(AuthPage());
  }
 }

 export default MainPage;
```

I also tried this:

This is Also Not working in redirection.

```
 import React from 'react'
 import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

  const ProtectedComponent = () => {
     if (authFails)
     return <Redirect to='/Signin'  />
     }
     return <div> My Protected Component </div>
   }
```

What is the proper way of implementing Redirect in React.js.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported BrowserRouter but you did not use it. Because you imported in wrong place.You need to use it in index.js.

Component BrowserRouter wraps the history object in the browser and passes it to down to component tree. Anywhere in the component tree you will be able to use the history object.

Index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

If you use "this" inside the function, this will point to global object which is "window" in the browser.

```
function logOut() {
 if (true) {
 localStorage.clear();
 this.props.history.push('/Signin');
    }
    }
```

In this snippet, 
this.props.history.push=windows.props.history.push
Since in global environment you didnt define the "props" object it will return undefined.

Solution is using arrow function.Arrow function use “this” value of containing function.

```
logout=()=>{if (true) {
 localStorage.clear();
 this.props.history.push('/Signin');
    }}
```

You do not even need to use

```
If(true)
```

You also have to create a signin page a register a route. We usually register routes in app.js

```
 import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

                <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />
                <Route path="/signin" exact component={signin} />
                <Redirect to="/not-found" />
```

Here I also registered a non-found router.This is a basic implementation for handling 404 pages. You need to create no-found component.

Comment: logout=()=>{if (true) {
 localStorage.clear();
 this.props.history.push('/Signin');
    }}            ---       In this component can I use in side the render method. with out passing any parameter It will through some error. (props undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both **Redirect** and **history** for the redirection in React.js.
But there is slightly difference in the way both are implemented.

Redirect is very explicit and history is implicit and less number of lines.

Please have a look at this link ([programmatically redirect in react.js](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/)) to know more on redirect in react.js with example.